# VS2019 SQL Project incorrect syntax trying to create Security Policy

Tags: azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019

Security Policies in Azure SQL has been around for quite a few years now, and trying to create a security policy in my sql project (VS2019) is returning incorrect syntax near SECURITY.

Does it look like I'm doing anything obvious wrong?

Azure SQL Targeted:

[image]

but still incorrect syntax near SECURITY

[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out for anyone else that runs into this.  I had to set the schema DSP ruleset to V12 in the .sqlproj file

Change this line:

```
  <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureDatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
```

to

```
  <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
```

It seems there is no way in the vs2019 gui yet to specify v12

Comment: Congratulations. You, you can mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I tested in Visual Studio 2017 and 2019, have the same error.

When I copy the SQL statement to the new query editor before execute it, the Error List will show the "Incorrect syntax" error:
[image]

But we still can run the query, there isn't any syntax error in query results:

Query executed successfully:
[image]

I think we can ignore the error in Error List,  just reference the query execute result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that the sql project in VS does not build, because this is an error.... so the DB cannot be deployed through azure devops.... I know there's a way to ignore certain errors in VS in the sql project.... any way to ignore errors too?